# How do I store a list of objects in field using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to code a payment process for an e-commerce solution and I want to gather all products in the shopping cart, but then inside a `List<OrderProducts>` and then store that list into an an object `Order`.

The POCO classes are below:

**Order.cs**

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser UserAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderProduct> OrderProduct { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

**OrderProduct.cs**

```
public class OrderProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

After running migrations and updating the database, it seems the `OrderProduct` column in the `Order` table does not even show in the database design.

Can someone please help or give a better solution based on the scenario above?

Comment: I think you need to show more code of how your configuring the table relationships in C# and pushing the schema to the Db.

Comment: @pmcilreavy do you mean by DbContext class? I have not done any configuration for table relationships. If you mean `Product` and `IdentityUser` please ignore them for now

Answer (score 0):

Change your OrderProduct class, then regenerate your migration:

```
public class OrderProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey(nameof(OrderId))]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I get this error `To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.` and in my other tables I have not had to specify attributes for keys. EF automatically recognises Id as PK and stores FK for objects